# Foreign Key Error When adding new records

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012

I am making a gym management system and I am using foreign keys in my tables. Everything was working perfectly, but after I added foreign keys I am getting the following error:

```
SQLException was Unhandled
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_member_info_instructor_info". The conflict occurred in database "D:\GYM MANAGEMENT 
SYSTEM\GYM MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\BIN\DEBUG\GMSDATABASE.MDF", table "dbo.instructor_info", 
column 'InstructorID'.

The statement has been terminated.
```

This error is pointing to this code:

```
public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new 
             System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
    cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

The above code is in my database collection class which is as following:

```
class GMSDConnectionClass
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;

    public string sql_string;
    public string strCon;

    public string Sql
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
    }

    public System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new 
         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

These are my tables which are being used when the error is thrown:

instructor_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[instructor_info] (
[InstructorID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[instructor]        NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[height]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[weight]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[chest]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[waist]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[shoulders]         NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[thighs]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[calves]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[memberID]          INT            NULL,
[date_of_admission] DATE           NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE          NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstructorID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_instructor_info_member_info] FOREIGN KEY ([memberID]) REFERENCES [dbo].
[member_info] ([memberID])
);
```

member_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member_info] (
[memberID]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[memberName]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[height]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[weight]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[chest]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[waist]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[shoulders]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[thighs]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[calves]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[instructorID]      INT           NULL,
[date_of_admission] DATE          NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([memberID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_member_info_instructor_info] FOREIGN KEY ([instructorID]) REFERENCES 
[dbo].[instructor_info] ([InstructorID])
);
```

This is my code for the save button on my form:

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = memberDataS.Tables[0].NewRow();

        row[0] = maxRowsMember + 1;
        row[1] = memberName.Text;
        row[2] = fatherName.Text;
        row[3] = age.Text;
        row[4] = address.Text;
        row[5] = contact.Text;
        row[6] = height.Text;
        row[7] = weight.Text;
        row[8] = chest.Text;
        row[9] = tricepBicep.Text;
        row[10] = waist.Text;
        row[11] = shoulders.Text;
        row[12] = thighs.Text;
        row[13] = calves.Text;
        row[14] = int.Parse(instructor.Text);
        row[15] = dateTimePicker1.Text;

        memberDataS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

        memberString.UpdateDatabase(memberDataS);

        maxRowsMember += 1;
        inc = maxRowsMember - 1;

        MessageBox.Show("Database updated");

        cancelBtn.Enabled = false;
        saveBtn.Enabled = false;
        addNewMemberBtn.Enabled = true;
    }
```

All help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you double checked that there is a corresponding ID in `instructor_info` that matches `instructor.text` when you call `saveBtn_click()`. Have you logged the value that gets assigned to `row[14]`?

Comment: @David The instructor_info table is empty. Do I have to fill that up in order to make it work???

Comment: Yes, the foreign key constraint checks and makes sure you only insert data which has a corresponding entry foreign table.

Comment: Okay let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your error may be resulting from row 14:

> row[14] = int.Parse(instructor.Text);

If my assumption about your code is correct, the instructor variable contains the VARCHAR(50) instructor name, not the INT IDENTITY value of instructorID.

Comment: instructor is a textbox on my form, i have declared it instructor so that I know the member's instructor ID goes in there.